# Testing huge pseudorandom sequence

Tags: testing, random, prng

I need to test two pseudorandom sequences:

- generated on 1 core processor;
- generated on 8 core processor.

For testing I will use Diehard test suite.
I faced the following problem. I need to test whole period of sequence, which is more than 2^32 digits, in file it's more than 4Gb, and I think that for 8 core processor it would be much more.
 Diehard documentation says:
`You must provide the binary file that DIEHARD expects---a file of 10 to 11 megabytes...`
The random generators, which is in Diehard test suite also generates ~11Mb files with random sequences. 
So the question is how I can test my huge file with sequence? And in which format it should be written? Now I'm just writting numbers, separating them with space, like this: 
`145 458 63 2 0 1489 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. For such big amount of data it is better to use Dieharder test suite.